# Replacement of a safety capacitor

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, safety

I would like to know if I can replace a safety Y2 capacitor (222m 300V - which is a 2.2nf-)with a safety X2 capacitor **temporarily**.
I'm in a hurry and I already ordered the replacement part but while I'm waiting I would like to know what do I have in my hands to keep the device working. My device has 220V input and 12V5A output.

I read [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/safety-capacitor-class-x-and-class-y-capacitors/) that :

> A Y2 capacitor can safely be used in place of an X2 capacitor, but an
> X2 capacitor should not be used in place of a Y2 capacitor. This is
> because, although an X2-type capacitor would work and filter noise
> sufficiently, it would not meet the line-to-ground safety standards.
> Y2 safety capacitors are more robust, are able to withstand higher
> peak impulse voltages, and are designed to fail open as opposed to
> failing short

But as I said it's for a very short period of time (like a 3 weeks or so)

Or maybe another idea ? Classic 1KV ceramic capacitor maybe can do the work ?
Thanks

**EDIT** :

The problem seems to be somwhere else I will open a new topic. Thanks !

Comment: fail open is different to fail short. How about just leave it absent for 3 weeks? If you put it in, do you feel lucky, punk?

Comment: Do you know why the Y2 capacitor failed in the first place? These parts are generally *extremely* robust.

Comment: Not at all, but I just realised that I have 2nf in capacitor mode and an O.L in resitance mode between it's pins. So maybe my conclusion isn't correct at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you are having to replace a Y class capacitor means that it failed in a benign manner without catching fire or smoke. You can't say the same for X class capacitors because these can fail short circuit.

In addition, you can use a Y class capacitor in front of a fuse but you can't with an X class capacitor hence, what you propose could be very risky. Y class capacitors are designed to fail open-circuit.

A Y2 capacitor is rated to withstand a peak impulse of 5 kV. An X2 capacitor is only rated for 2.5 kV peak impulse.